# Can't connect to docker process

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm using boot2docker on windows
Docker version:
Client version: 0.12.0
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 14680bf
Server version: 0.12.0
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 14680bf

I'm basically going through the user guide, everything is working as intended but on browsing to the training flask app (http://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/) my browser can't connect to the web server.

I've tried every version of my ip address(es), host name, ... nothing. Always "can't connect".

The docker image is running fine:

> 8e9f917617ef        training/webapp:latest   python app.py       15 seconds ago
>        Up 14 seconds       0.0.0.0:49153->5000/tcp   kickass_carson

Since this is the basic guide, I would expect all bases covered ... but perhaps something windows (or boot2docker) specific isn't mentioned. Just can't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

creack gave me the hint - I hadn't looked at boot2docker specifically. It has it's own ip address - typically this one:
$ boot2docker ip
   192.168.59.103

So now doing http:// 192.168.59.103:49153 I got 'hello world'.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how boot2docker works on windows, but check your VM config (within virtualbox) and make sure the ports 49000 to 50000 are forwarded to the host. You should then be able to access your flask app from `http://localhost:<port>`

Comment: Right, this is one of the boot2docker features: $ boot2docker ip 192.168.59.103 ... boot2docker ip didn't work for me (ssh problem)

Answer (score 2):

The fact "boot2docker ip" doesn't work on windows by default is a pain

As Bjorn did, I tried on .103 and it worked, but this is pure luck....

When doing a netstat -r you see the entire address range is going to .3 , which must be the external VM address.
    192.168.59.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.59.3
    192.168.59.3  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.59.3
  192.168.59.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.59.3

Finding out that the ultimate address is 103 is a challenge I couldn't solve